# Accessing images in iis hosted directory from php page

Tags: php, apache, iis, virtual-path, directory-browsing

I have a php page that will needs to navigate to other directory that is hosted in iis in order to access the images but it keep telling me file not found.

**IIS**

`D:\website\images` (the website folder here is already a website hosted by IIS)

**Apache**

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\page.php
```

From page.php, I try to access the image with relative path. So the path i tried is `../../website/images/whatever.jpg` but i can't access it. Any settings that needs to be done in IIS?

Btw, I can access it using browser though.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to access the image from a script or are you trying to make it display on a page?

Comment: why are you using iis for php ? use nginx if you want fast-cgi support or apache2

Comment: "the website folder here is already a website hosted by IIS" - looks like you're trying to access the file via the local file system; so the IIS part of your question is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: yes I am trying to access the images through local file system but since i can't, i'm wondering is it due to iis that has somehow blocked the permission